# find text in id then find class in the same id

Tags: java, html, selenium, if-statement

The code below asks for a user input (year) and i want to use the same input to first check if the text (for eg. 2014) input by a user in the `div class` is in that particular `PagePostsSectionPaglet` and if yes, find `div class="_5sem"`in the same div id to perform action on its other webelements?

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
        System.out.println("Enter a year: ");
        String year = reader.next(); // Scans the next token of the input 

        WebElement yearButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@data-key,'" + year + "')]"));                        
        yearButton.click();
```

[image]

Comment: what it is reruting when you print `PagePostsSectionPagelet.size() and tds.size()`

Comment: Your code isn't trying to print anything. Please show more code of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a xpath which look for ids starts-with your constant part of ids like `"//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]"`. Then you can find all the divs and sort in list webelement by this xpath. Finally you can iterate over the list and if one has the text "2014" then you can click or whatever you want with it. See the code below:

```
List <WebElement> PagePostsSectionPagelet = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')]"));

for (WebElement elm : PagePostsSectionPagelet){
        System.out.println(elm.findElement(By.cssSelector(".clearfix > span")).text)    
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried your answer and it says cannot find symbol symbol: variable text location: variable elm of type WebElement after adding a () in the if statement. 

also, if the text is a user input read using a scanner, how can i go about iterating the list to search for the text input if i dont know what text will the user write?

Comment: yes, that was my initial intention, thus i have edited my question accordingly. sorry for the confusion.

Comment: so do you want to insert "2014" in textbox then check it?

Comment: i want to check a user-input value so it might be not 2014 either. the only thing that changes is the text in `<div class="clearfix">`, the rest `PagePostsSectionPagelet` and `(className("_5sem"))` remains the same. @mesut

Comment: did you try this `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".clearfix > span")).text` if you have more `clearfix` you need to iterate.

Comment: i only have 1 clearfix, i have tried this instead `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'PagePostsSectionPagelet')text(),'" + year + "']"));` as the above one does not return the element

Comment: @dark_space it is better add/upload html code to test it in my machine

Comment: I tried it with python and this works `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".clearfix > span").text` it prints `2014`. You did mistakes there is no `.` in between `).text` and there are more than one `clearfix` class. I updated the code. Hope you would upvote.

Comment: im not sure why but yours doesnt work on java, nonetheless, your code was helpful so thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may try something `XPATH` like- If it exists the it will return `webelement` otherwise `None`.

```
//div[@id='PagePostsSectionPagelet']//span[text()='2014']/preceding::div[2]/following-sibling::div[1]//div[@class='_5sem']
```

Selenium expression like-

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='PagePostsSectionPagelet']//span[text()='2014']/preceding::div[2]/following-sibling::div[1]//div[@class='_5sem']"))
```